# Guava MinMaxPriorityQueue instantiation

Tags: java, guava

I am having trouble instantiating a MinMaxPriorityQueue from Guava (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html#orderedBy%28java.util.Comparator%29). I don't really understand what the builder it refers to is. I am not good at interpreting Javadocs.

I have tried doing this:

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<T bob = new MinMaxPriorityQueue<T>(null, int);
```

Which throws the error `The constructor MinMaxPriorityQueue<T>(MinMaxPriorityQueue.Builder<? super E>, int) is not visible`.

I tried doing this:

`MinMaxPriorityQueue<T> bob = MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();`

Which throws the error: `MinMaxPriorityQueue<T> bob = MinMaxPriorityQueue.create();`.

Could someone please explain how to instantiate a MinMaxPriorityQueue with a maximum size N and a comparator NodeComparator? Thanks!

Comment: This is my fault and I am suitably shamed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javadoc of the method you linked to says that this method returns an instance of [`MinMaxPriorityQueue.Builder`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.Builder.html). This class has various methods to configure and create a queue (with a max size, an initial content, etc.)

So you just need

```
MinMaxPriorityQueue<Node> bob = 
    MinMaxPriorityQueue.orderedBy(nodeComparator)
                       .maximumSize(1000)
                       .create();
```